# How to add value in database using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Model classes:

```
public class BulkAttendance
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeLabourGroup {  get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public int FinancialYearId { get; set;}
    public int ApprovalStatus { get; set; }
    public int ApprovalLevel { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyPrecision { get; set; }
    public List<BulkAttendaceDetail> AttendanceDetail { get; set; }

}

public class BulkAttendaceDetail 
{
    public string AttendanceId { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateWorked { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutTime { get; set; }
    public int Employeeid { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName {  get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int Work { get; set; }
    public decimal OverTime { get; set; }
    public decimal OverTimeAmount { get; set; }
    public string WorkCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string WorkShortName { get; set; }
    public decimal OvertimeRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOut { get; set; }
    public decimal SalaryAmount { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to post `employeeAttendance` in my project. The problem is  `BulkAttendance` model id is database generated. I want to assign the `Id` value to `AttendanceId` in `BulkAttendance` detail model - how can I approach this situation?

This how I try to insert `Attendance` of employee into database

```
public async Task BulkAttendanceEntry(List<BulkAttendance> attendances)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (var attendance in attendances)
        {
            await _bulkAttendanceContext.tbl_AttendanceMaster.AddAsync(attendance);

            if (attendance.AttendanceDetail != null && attendance.AttendanceDetail.Any())
            {
                foreach(var attendanceDetail in attendance.AttendanceDetail)
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
         throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: Start by not SHOUTING at us in the title. Did you see the format of the other questions?

Comment: `await _bulkAttendanceContext.tbl_AttendanceMaster.AddAsync(attendance); await _bulkAttendanceContext.SaveChangesAsync();` . Please use SaveChangesAsync, then the Id will be generated.

Comment: When you add a parent item containing children navigation properties, by default the DbContext will treat these children as inserts automatically, so Jason's comment should be all you need. There is no need to explicitly add the details. HOWEVER note that this will be a problem when you want to update entities because EF will treat untracked entities as New, (insert) regardless of whether they have IDs or not. I don't recommend sending detached entities as this poses all kinds of problems and risks in a system.

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework Core, if you want to define a **one to many** relation between two entities like yours, you must add in the child entity **BulkAttendanceDetail** a reference to the parent entity **BulkAttendance**. So a foreign key will be created, in the child table, pointing to the parent table. When you will correctly add a new entity to BulkAttendanceDetail table, the new row will have a reference property (the foreign key) containing the corresponding id of its parent row in the parent BulkAttendance table.
To make this mechanism, You must modify your BulkAttendanceDetail class:

```
public class BulkAttendanceDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }  //primary key of BulkAttendanceDetail table                                    
    public int BulkAttendanceId { get; set; } //foreign key to BulkAttendance table                                   
    BulkAttendance BulkAttendance { get; set; } //parent class
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateWorked { get; set; }
    public DateTime LoginTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogoutTime { get; set; }
    public int Employeeid { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public int WorkId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public int Work { get; set; }
    public decimal OverTime { get; set; }
    public decimal OverTimeAmount { get; set; }
    public string WorkCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string WorkShortName { get; set; }
    public decimal OvertimeRate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeIn { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeOut { get; set; }
    public decimal SalaryAmount { get; set; }
}
```

**BulkAttendanceId** property will be your foreign key. When you will add to your context a new BulkAttendance object (parent) containing a populated child list:

`List<BulkAttendanceDetail> AttendanceDetail`

the foreign keys will be automatically generated at the moment of saving your new parent object:

`await _bulkAttendanceContext.SaveChangesAsync();`